# Creating AMI from private ISO?

Tags: iso, amazon-ami, packer

I am trying to figure out the best practice for creating an AMI out of a private ISO? Is there a method for doing this that anyone could recommend? I would like to do so using Packer, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of anyway to import an ISO to an AMI, because you are comparing apples and oranges. And ISO is a filesystem wrapper, where an AMI is a virtual machine image.

What you can do, it build a packer build (eg. just do a bare install) and export it to an OVA (with VMWare or Virtualbox for example.)

You can then use the ec2-import-image command which is part of the awscli and import your OVA to EC2, which will start an ec2 job which will convert your OVA to an AMI in your account.

Amazon [documents the process.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html) HTH